# How can I programmatically shrink a 3D box?

Tags: geometry

I have 8 points of a 3D box, they are generated like so.

```
float points[8][3]; // [0] is first corner, and [7] is the second corner
points[0] = corner1;
points[7] = corner2;

for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        points[i][j] = points[((i >> (2-j)) & 1) * 7][j];
    }
}
```

How could I shrink the box by 2 units from each side programmatically, and dynamically? The points change every few minutes.

Here's a "screenshot" of the corners that I have = 1 is [0] and 2 is [7]. At the right side, is what I'm trying to achieve - scale it down.

[image]

Comment: Are you scaling about the center of the box or a corner?

Comment: Yes, I'm scaling the center, but the points I have are 2 corners.

Answer (score 0):

For shrinking relative to center:

```
center = (corner1 + corner2) / 2
diag = corner2 - corner1
diaglen = diag.Length
coeff = (diaglen - 2 * Sqrt(3)) / diaglen           //check for positive
for every vertex:
  new.X = center.X + (old.X - center.X) * coeff
  same for y,z
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        point[i][j] = point[((i >> (2 - j)) & 1) * 7][j];
    }
}

if(offset != 0.0)
{
    float center[2];
    center[0] = ((point[0][0] + point[7][0]) / 2);
    center[1] = ((point[0][1] + point[7][1]) / 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            if(point[i][j] < center[j])
            {
                point[i][j] += offset;
            }

            else
            {
                point[i][j] -= offset;
            }
        }
    }
}
```